# How to download a PDF from an URL that checks sessions and cookies, using python and selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, session, cookies, download

**What I am trying to do-**

I am trying to automate-

1. Login to an Employee Self Service Portal
2. Click on couple of links to get to the page where Salary slips are shown in an embedded PDF
3. Download the PDF

I have been able to accomplish step 1 and 2 using code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

#open the site and enter userid and password
browser.get('http://eportal.erp.bsnl.co.in/irj/portal')
userName = browser.find_element_by_css_selector ('#logonuidfield')
userName.send_keys('12345678')
password = browser.find_element_by_css_selector ('#logonpassfield')
password.send_keys('12345678')
password.submit()

#clicking on couple of links to get to the salary statement page 
employeess = browser.find_element_by_css_selector ('#navNodeAnchor_1_1')
employeess.click()
browser.switch_to.frame('pb_100693274')
browser.switch_to.frame('isolatedWorkArea')
payslip = browser.find_element_by_xpath ('//*[@id="aaabGFON.AreaGroupViewStatic.QuickLink12"]/span')
payslip.click()

#get the url for embedded PDF
browser.switch_to.frame('pb_100693274')
browser.switch_to.frame('isolatedWorkArea')
browser.switch_to.frame('aaabLDOL.VcRfwIFrameView.RfwIframe')
url = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="plugin"]').get_attribute('src')
```

When I print the 'url' I get the url as -(http://eportal.erp.bsnl.co.in/webdynpro/dispatcher/sap.com/ess~rem/PaySlip2/~wd_key181_1513145812322/unknown.pdf?sap-wd-download=1&sap-wd-cltwndid=WID1513145774222&sap-wd-secure-id=32c76516dfcd11e794e8001a4b09cbd80843296581&sap-ext-sid=yUx3bKEyzSr2CqpOKogWEQ--3Kt0yPvk8X20QivyLzFWEw--%2Fpcd%3Aportal_content%2Fcom.hclt.f_bsnl_content%2Fcom.hclt.f_bp%2Fcom.hclt.f_hcm%2Fcom.hclt.f_ess%2Fcom.hclt.f_copied%2Fcom.hclt.f_roles%2Fcom.sap.pct.erp.ess.employee_self_service%2Fcom.sap.pct.erp.ess.employee_self_service%2Fcom.sap.pct.erp.ess.area_benefits_payment%2Fcom.sap.pct.erp.ess.paycheck%2Fsap.com%2Fess%7Erem%2FPaySlip2%2Fbase&sap-wd-norefresh=X&sap-ep-version=7.0106.20091228220110.0000)

which is dynamically generated, so I tried to download the PDF by using wget

```
import wget
wget.download(url)
```

and the result is-
'unknown.pdf'

but when I check this file its only 1Kb and opening it gives 'file may be corrupted message'. The file should be of about 80Kb size.

**What I have tried-**
I tried to open the above long url in a **New Tab** and it shows me the PDF. However when I try to open the same url in a **New Window** I get "Session Expired" error, which I believe is the reason why I am unable to download the complete file.

I suspect this means that the server checks for the session/cookies before sending the file over.

Is there any way to download the PDF file from above given url, from the same browser window which was launched by Chromedriver for logging in OR passing the sessions/cookies along with the url for downloading the file?

Comment: Grab the cookies with selenium and add them to your request along with the same user agent. You could also inject a script in the page to download the file via `XMLHttpRequest`. Another way would be to disable the pdf  viewer with the preferences, to click the link and to wait for file to be downloaded.

Comment: Florent B. can u provide reference or code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open chrome with the right options. You should then be able to download the file through chrome with a call to `browser.get(url)`.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

# define chrome options and open chrome
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs',  {
    "download.default_directory": '/path/to/download-directory', # <-- enter your download dir here
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True
    }
)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# download pdf
browser.get(url-to-pdf)
```